# SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633) Anaconda Prompt Error

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda, python-3.10, conda-forge

When I try to install python on Windows using anaconda, I get the following error:
SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2633) Anaconda Prompt Error

How can I fix?

I have already try to set ssl verification parameter to false using:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

This Pc is workstation so I can use it at another network.

I have tried doing the same on another laptop which is connected same Wlan Network. That works without any problem.

Here is a log if the error:

```
 C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\>conda install -c conda-forge python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


## Package Plan

environment location: C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\gkk

added / updated specs:
- keepalive

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-3.10.4              |hcf16a7b_0_cpython        16.2 MB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        16.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

bzip2              conda-forge/win-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h8ffe710_4
keepalive          conda-forge/noarch::keepalive-0.5-pyhd8ed1ab_6
libffi             conda-forge/win-64::libffi-3.4.2-h8ffe710_5
libzlib            conda-forge/win-64::libzlib-1.2.11-h8ffe710_1013
pip                conda-forge/noarch::pip-22.0.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
python             conda-forge/win-64::python-3.10.4-hcf16a7b_0_cpython
python_abi         conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.10-2_cp310
setuptools         conda-forge/win-64::setuptools-60.10.0-py310h5588dad_0
sqlite             conda-forge/win-64::sqlite-3.37.1-h8ffe710_0
tk                 conda-forge/win-64::tk-8.6.12-h8ffe710_0
tzdata             conda-forge/noarch::tzdata-2022a-h191b570_0
wheel              conda-forge/noarch::wheel-0.37.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
xz                 conda-forge/win-64::xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_1

Proceed (\[y\]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages
python-3.10.4        | 16.2 MB   |                                                                            |   0%

SSLError(SSLError(1, '\[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC\] decryption failed or bad record mac (\_ssl.c:2633)'))
```

I am expecting without error:

> ```
> Preparing transaction: done
> Verifying transaction: done 
> Executing transaction: done
> ```

Comment: your conda SSL disable command solved my issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this error when updating conda with:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

which led to:

```bash
[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2622)
[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2622)
```

I found two downloads that had been stopped at lower percentages (mkl and markdown):

```bash
jupyter_server-1.23. | 399 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
mkl-2023.1.0         | 155.6 MB  | ###6                                                                         |   5%
executing-0.8.3      | 18 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
```

```bash
snappy-1.1.9         | 2.2 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
markdown-3.4.1       | 148 KB    | ################################8                                            |  43%
numexpr-2.8.4        | 128 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
```

It is likely that the SSL errors came just from these two broken downloads. That is why I reran the command, and it worked:

```bash
Downloading and Extracting Packages
mkl-2023.1.0         | 155.6 MB  | ############################################################################ | 100%
markdown-3.4.1       | 148 KB    | ################################################################################################################# | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: -

    Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
    More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

    For example:

        $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
        $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py


done
```

I did not need to change the ssl settings for this since I have not touched the settings before.

Though this more or less what the other answer also says, I try to make clearer that running again - with the ssl setting to true if you had changed it before - might be all that is needed.

Comment: approve, just retry

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and running the opposite worked for me:

```bash
~/miniconda3/bin/conda config --set ssl_verify true
```